# Codeigniter Autoload class is not working in ubuntu

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, autoload

i am using  codeigniter framework for development .

I used a class Users.php as the base class. all other classes are derived fro this  class
like class ads extends Users.

For this i added this code in config file

```
 function __autoload($class="Users")
 {
 if(strpos($class, 'CI_') !== 0)
  {
  @include_once( APPPATH . 'controllers/'. $class . EXT );
  }
 }
```

it was working fine in my localhost when i was using windows ....now i just installed 
ubuntu 12.o4 and try lo load my page ...but it is showing blank

please help me

thank you

Comment: enable `error_reporting` in index.php. Then you can see the error. May be case sensitive issue.

Comment: yes it was case sensitive issue ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think It may be file name problem. You should use

```
class User extends CI_Controller {.....
```

in your User.php file.. In short Class name should exact match with your file name. Because linux OS is case sensitive..